# vba calculate days between dates in two cells, only return a value if both cells have a date

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to calculate days between dates in two cells, but it returns an error value if column X has no date.  I want the code to only return a value if there is a date in column X, but I don't know how to do that.  I am new to VBA.  Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

```
Sub CalcDays()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

With Range("AA2:AA" & LastRow)
    [AA:AA] = [X:X-Z:Z]
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. I've never seen that `[AA:AA] = [X:X-Z:Z]` syntax before inside a with. Definitely going to steal that.

Comment: @JNevill  Works like the *EVALUATE()* function

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I'm astounded that I've never come across this. I'm tickled that I've learned something new!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
[AA:AA] = [if(X:X="", "", if(Z:Z="", "", X:X-Z:Z))]
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much!